# ng2-bootstrap datepicker with formControlName attribute

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms, ng2-bootstrap

I've created form using Angular 2 containing autocomplete and datepicker (ng2-bootstrap).
Everything is implemented using FormGroup and FormControls.

```
this.searchForm = new FormGroup({
  dateStart: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
  dateEnd: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
  origin: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
  destination: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
});
```

Autocomplete fields work as expected (in every aspect: logic, form validation, formControlName attribute).

Unfortunately, datepicker controls are not working properly with Model Driven Forms and formControlName. I had to use ngModel to bind user data, but I'm looking for more complex solution to control these all fields from FormGroup level and to take care of the validation.

**Current HTML code responsible for datepicker:**

```
<datepicker
  [(ngModel)]="searchForm.value.dateEnd"
  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
  [showWeeks]="false"
  [startingDay]="1"
  [minDate]="minDateEnd"
  [initDate]="minDateEnd"
  [collapse]="isCalEndVisible"
></datepicker>
```

**The expected result:**

```
<datepicker
  formControlName="dateEnd"
  [showWeeks]="false"
  [startingDay]="1"
  [minDate]="minDateEnd"
  [initDate]="minDateEnd"
  [collapse]="isCalEndVisible"
></datepicker>
```

Any idea, folks?

Comment: I'm not sure if their changelog is up to date, but they apparently have not yet released reactive forms support. This should be coming soon as there was a pull for it 3 days ago which closed out a few issues.

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/issues/893

Comment: ng2-bootstrap components does not support form controls, you can create your own component and include the ng2-datepicker and customize it to become form control, see this page: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html

Comment: I've studied that page with custom form controls but wanted to know whether ng2-bootstrap's gonna implement any improvements in the near future or whether we have any uncomplicated (golden mean) solution to solve this drawback. So...it remains for me nothing else than the creation of custom ng2-bootstrap datepicker to use it with ReactiveFormsModule. NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR - I'm comming :) thanks